# Facebook iOS SDK: authorize with permissions requires 2 attempts

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an app that still uses the deprecated Facebook class to connect with Facebook.  If I authorize with no extended permissions, everything works fine.  But if I do include permissions, the first round trip to authorize always fails (even though it gets a valid token!).  Am I missing a step?

Here's the code to initiate Facebook authorization for the app

```
- (IBAction) doConnect:(id)sender
{
    NSArray* permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"email",@"publish_actions",nil];
    [self.facebook authorize:permissions];
}
```

Here's the code that gets invoked after the user has granted permissions and control returns to my app.  The url always includes a nice looking token, even the first time through.

```
// handle the incoming url from app switching
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

And here's the FBSessionDelegate method that gets invoked after a successful connect.  Even though the url above contained a token, it's gone the first time we get here. But if I invoke the doConnect method above, the token will be present when we get here.

```
// FBSessionDelegate
- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    if( [self.facebook accessToken] == nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"Had an access token above, but not now!");

        // If I reinvade the doConnect: method again, it will work!!!
    }
    // ...
```

}

Looking deep in the sdk code in FBSession.m, it seems that the requested permissions haven't been associated with the new token first time through, causing the session to ignore the new token.  First time through, cachedPermissions is always an empty list

```
    // get the cached permissions, and do a subset check
    NSArray *cachedPermissions = [tokenInfo objectForKey:FBTokenInformationPermissionsKey];
    BOOL isSubset = [FBSession areRequiredPermissions:permissions
                                 aSubsetOfPermissions:cachedPermissions];
```

Comment: You may want to think about separating read/publish permission requests so that you only request read permissions the first time round. See what happens if you only ask for email initially. Does the email permission show up in the cached permission list?

Comment: Worth a try, but no luck.  FBSession's cachedPermissions seems destined to always be nil first time through, so it seems like it will always take a second pass. I do notice that the Facebook dialog that requests permissions in safari is correctly asking for the extended permissions during the first pass.  The token never changes between the first and second pass.

Comment: @CAbernathy If you post an answer clarifying that using this deprecated part of the Facebook sdk api with any extended permissions will require a second attempt to be successful, I'll accept it and we can close this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for two types of permissions, a read type (email) and a write type (publish_actions).

You should be using the latest Facebook SDK, v3.1.1 and you'll have to split up read and writes separately - especially if you wish to support iOS6. You can only ask for reads initially. See the note in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/ and the section on asking for read and writes separately.

Comment: Thanks C. Just a warning to anyone who is using the old deprecated api - it does appear to have a bug, so you may have to use the double-try approach to get it to work.  But I doubt many people will have reason to use the old api at this point.

Comment: Thanks C Abernathy!  it worked.
After granting publish permissions if user logs out and logs in again to our facebook app then we have to ask publish permissions again?  Is there any way to avoid asking publish permissions more than 1 times ?  After granting permissions first time When I logout and again openSessionWIthReadPermissions, then it does not contain previous publish permissions by default.

Comment: When the app opens, you could try using openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO - this would check if there's a session from cache and use that session to open. This would also make sure any previous publish permissions (and any others) are also pulled in.

Comment: What about the case where you just want to share a photo on Facebook. I don't want to require the user to login to Facebook in my app until they are ready to share their photo.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook SDK 3.1, use [FBSession activeSession]'s

```
reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions: defaultAudience:completionHandler:
```

For Facebook SDK 3.2, use [FBSession activeSession]'s

```
requestNewPublishPermissions: defaultAudience:completionHandler:
```

Answer (score 0):

we can authorise user in single request. It does not need two times attempt. To achieve this what we need do is "We need to ask for publish permission first". Call the below method

```
let fbLoginMngr =  FBSDKLoginManager();
fbLoginMngr.logOut()
fbLoginMngr.logInWithPublishPermissions
```

it will ask first profile details then asks for requested publish permission. Once we get a call back we query to Graph api to extract the profile data like below.

```
let fbRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me",    parameters:self.FB_REQ_PARAMS);
                fbRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        debugPrint(result)
                    } else {
                        handleError(error)
                    }
                }
```